# Chickenbutt Equivalent

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Is there an equivalent to the word *chickenbutt*, which is commonly used by young children in America, in German? If so, what is it?

> Guess what? Chickenbutt.
>
> You're a chickenbutt.

Comment: I guess it would help if you describe the meaning of _chickenbutt_. People here are supposed to have good German skills, but English skills are not necessarily as good.

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chicken%20butt

Comment: One might mention here the ***Zickezacke - Hühnerkacke*** rhyme which once was popular in youthful parts of German society (and was reflected by the *Hätte, hätte - Fahrradkette* response by candidate for Federal Chancelor  Peer Steinbrück in 2013 on questions about mistakes in his election campaign team).

Comment: The chant is *Zickezacke Zickezacke! Heu Heu Heu!*, similar to En. *Oggy Oggy Oggy! Oi Oi Oi!* often performed as a call-response sequence between cheer-on and crowd. If akin, these reflect a common theme. The meaning of *Zickezacke* and *oggy* is obscure. Compare a proposal, *oggy* from *hoggan*, note that /h/ may be lost, ignore the proposed meaning. Compare *Hick-hack* "hin und her". Assume that *Haken* and *Zacken* are rather similar in meaning. Assume sound change leads to altered meter. Wonder what *Oi, Heu* might mean, certainly affirmation. *Hühnerkacke* is the opposite, *chickenshit*.

Comment: @Vectory - Both *Zickezacke, zickezacke, hoi, hoi, hoi* (to use the other common spelling) and "Zickezacke - Hühnerkacke* exist. It is possible that the second is an ironic variation of the first. Still it exists.

Answer (score 7):

**First of all what is this chickenbutt?**

> A win or lose game. The questioner tries to catch the questionee off guard by asking "Guess what?" as if they really have news.
>
> A: Guess What?
>
> B: What?
>
> A: Chicken Butt!
>
> In the above senario person A wins the game, had person B said Chicken Butt in response they would have won the game and person A loses.

[source](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chicken%20butt)

There is a similar German "game" with tricking the questionee into saying a certain word which rhymes with a funny (cough cough) response. Here are some examples

1.

> A: Sag mal Tomate
>
> B: Tomate
>
> A: Deine Oma kann Karate (derber: Dein Pimmel kann Karate)

2.

> A: Sag mal Wolle
>
> B: Wolle
>
> A: 10 Minuten Arschkontrolle

3.

> A: Sag mal Ananas
>
> B: Ananas
>
> A: Deine Hose ist nass

4.

> A: Sag mal Leitung
>
> B: Leitung
>
> A: Du stehst nackt in der Zeitung

5.

> A: Sag mal Mütze
>
> B: Mütze
>
> A: Zehn Minuten Liegestütze

6.

> A: Sag mal Messer
>
> B: Messer
>
> A: Popelfresser

7.

> A: Sag mal Fenster
>
> B: Fenster
>
> A: Deine Eltern sind Gespenster

or similar

> A: Was gibt 4 + 4?
>
> B: 8
>
> A: Du hast in die Hose gemacht

Comment: *Oder soll ich Ananas machen?* – Rocker Herbert explodiert: *Wenn hier einer Anna nass macht, dann bin ich das ja wohl!*

Comment: One should add that this makes a very very childish impression. Even in elementary school there are kids who think others are idiots because they say this stuff too often. Which can even just mean more than once :-)

Comment: @Janka https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFUqD61JYMk&t=34s ^^

Comment: Thanks for excellent example from German subcultural areas. - Question however: The English version does not rhyme really well: "Guess what - Chickenbutt"... hm! Wouldn't for example "Guess what - chicken bot" rhyme better? And do American children not feel uncomfortable with the underperforming rhyme? Or is that game from a region where they pronounce "what" like "butt"?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I'm not sure whether that matters, or can be rhymed, but I guess maybe disappointment is the goal?

Answer (score 5):

At least in Austria, the game corresponding to the Chickenbutt game (as described by mtwde) is ["der Stoascheißer Koarl"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinschei%C3%9Fer_Karl) (in standard German "der Steinscheißer Karl"). In this game, you trick the other person into asking "Wer?" ("who"), upon which you answer "der Stoascheißer Koarl", thereby winning the game.

Comment: Is the word *Stoascheißer* seen as appropriate for children?

Comment: That depends. When I was a child, I heard a friends father say to him "Scheiß dir nicht ins Hemd" ("Don't shit your shirt", apparently from a time when children wore long shirts instead of trousers?) I certainly considered that inappropriate, but my friends father didn't. But even in my family, saying Stoascheißer Koarl wasn't seen as inappropriate.

Comment: Und auch hier ein Belegvideo, Hader spielt Hader: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_HjF5CF1ik

Comment: @Schroder  Why should *Schtoascheißer* not be appropriate for children? They very much enjoy talking about excrements at a certain age.

Comment: @sgf compare *Kleid*, *Kleidung*, *shirt, skirt, short, shorts*, *Schurz, Schuerze* and especially old fashioned senses of *Rock*, "Kleidung".